# How to run selenium standalone jar file automatically?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

Before running any scripts in Remote machine I need to run the Selenium Stand alone server jar file in the remote machine manually via a command line. As my scripts will be run through TFS Build every night, is there any way to integrate some code in the test script or even the Build process to automatically start the jar file in the remote machine before the tests start running?
FYI : My selenium Webdriver tests are written in C#.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't leave the server running on the remote machine all the time? Why do you need to start it only when a build completes?

Comment: Patrick is your remove machine is windows? if you say windows i have a solution for it.

Comment: @JeffC: I can't see no reason why I should leave it running all time, but I thought it was a good idea to start the RC when the Build starts. I could leave it running all the time by adding it as a Windows Service I just need to find out how to do it.

Comment: @Mona: Yes, the remote machine is a windows machine. Do you have a good solution for that?

Comment: @Patrick : i posted a answer what we follow, may be it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you can create a .bat file and add it to your windows startup folder or you can include the script to execute the BAT file.

Just create a notepad with below command and save it as .bat file.if you double click it, you can see selenium server is running. then to your requirement, add it to the startup folder or include in your script to execute .bat file.

```
java -jar C:\Users\mona\Downloads\softwares\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.0.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Mona, this is much better than trying to include the Selenium RC as part of the Windows Service. I just learned a new thing, much appreciated.

Comment: You can try it. If it worked. Please accept solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you want you can to start testing at certain times during the week. And they are fixed you can start any process by using Windows Scheduler service.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

I would just schedule the remote service to run right before I start testing.

Comment: Not a bad idea, as my Build is schedule to run a specific time, I can schedule a task to automatically start the RC mn before the tests are run. I also came across this http://thecrumb.com/2012/11/19/starting-selenium-rc-as-a-service-for-jenkins/    which I may need to try also.